# getting live data from server continuosly and refelect changes in html in angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a live dashboard that displays live data from server. Live data on server means data is changing continuously on server.
I want to keep track of changes and reflect it on my dashboard template.

I want the best approach for the requirement. Please, help.
Although, I have yet to start working on this dashboard. How I will do this is below. Although, being new to angular2, have little idea to achieve this task? Please help with best approach.

### service.ts

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
    @Injectable()
    export class DataService {

      constructor(private http: Http) {
      }

 // here method of getting live data (changing continuosly on server)
// How to keep track of json data changes on server and pass it on component template


    getPIWSData(clientJson): Observable<any[]> {
     console.warn('Retriving Data from  Server' + JSON.stringify(clientJson));

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    returnthis.http.post('http://10.40.10oardDatasingle', clientJson)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

      private extractData(res: Response) {
        const body = res.json();
        return body || [];
      }

      private handleError(error: any) {
        const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
          error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg);
        console.log('Server Error!');
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
      }
    }
```

### dashboard.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: '',
  templateUrl: './.html',
  styleUrls: ['./acomponent.css']
})

name: string;

constructor( public jsonDataService: DataService){}
   this.jsonDataService.getPIWSData().subscribe(
          function (success) {
            this.data = success;
            this.getdata(success);
          },
          error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error)));

getdata(jsonData){
console.log(jsonData);

// Here, handling data
this.name  =  <----------------------from jsonData

}
```

### dashboard.component.html

```
<div>{{name}} </div>     <----here name coming from server should change 
                       if there data changes
```

Answer (score 0):

From the nature of observables the data will update on changes, the problem is that the post request just returns once. To achieve what you want you need to change your server to use sockets or a similar technology.

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest best approach with example to  achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend WebSockets, I don't know what is on your backend so I will give you only a solution for the frontend.

**websocket.service.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {

    private subject: Rx.Subject<MessageEvent>;

    public connect(url: string): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
        if (!this.subject) {
            this.subject = this.create(url);
        }
        return this.subject
    }

    private create(url: string): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
        let ws = new WebSocket(url);

        let observable = Rx.Observable.create((obs: Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
            ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
            ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
            ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);

            return ws.close.bind(ws);
        });

        let observer = {
            next: (data: Object) => {
                if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                    ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            }
        };

        return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);
    }

}
```

**ws-object.ts**

```
export class WsObject{
    constructor(
        public type: string,
        public data: any
    ) { }
}
```

**component.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ComponentService {

    private websocketUrl= 'ws://backendurl';
    public messages: Subject<WsObject>;

    constructor(
        private websocketService: WebsocketService
    ) {
        this.messages = <Subject<WsObject>>websocketService.connect(this.websocketUrl).map((response: MessageEvent): WsObject=> {
        let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        return data;
        }
    );
    }
}
```

**somemething.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component',
    templateUrl: 'something.component.html'
})
export class SomethingComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private componentService: ComponentService ,
    ) {
        componentService.messages.subscribe(msg => {
            this.handleIncomingMessages(msg);
        });
    }

    handleIncomingMessages(msg) {
      //here comes the data on every change
    }
}
```