# Update Angular app data in real time using websocket

Tags: spring, angular, angular5, sockjs

I have API written in Spring on server side also managed websocket code that opens socket and continuously responds with some data (for example `/getlikes` returns number of likes).

How do I call this API in service that continuously checks for updated values (I don't want to use any time interval for service call)?

Comment: Once a client has subscribed to a websocket endpoint, simply send your messages from the server at any time, and all subscribed clients will receive the messages.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [sockjs-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sockjs-client) and do somethjing like this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private serverUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/socket'
  private title = 'WebSockets chat';
  private stompClient;

  constructor(){
    this.initializeWebSocketConnection();
  }

  public initializeWebSocketConnection(){
    let ws = new SockJS(this.serverUrl);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
    let that = this;
    this.stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
      that.stompClient.subscribe("/chat", (message) => {
        if(message.body) {
          $(".chat").append("<div class='message'>"+message.body+"</div>")
          console.log(message.body);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  public sendMessage(message){
    this.stompClient.send("/app/send/message" , {}, message);
    $('#input').val('');
  }

}
```

you can find a full tutorial on this in this [article](https://medium.com/oril/spring-boot-websockets-angular-5-f2f4b1c14cee)

Comment: @anirudha  hie thanks for reply ,i am using  spring server (not node js) can we do this SockJs and StompJS

Comment: You can use [sockjs-client-for-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sockjs-client)

Comment: thanks i followed the documentation of sockjs and stompjs can you please add some demo which demonstrate calling api from service file and component.ts using that api updating results on ui.

Comment: I updated the answer. go thriuth the links I've shared.

Comment: hi @anirudha i will go through this , can you please tell me : i need to update my dashboard values in realtime , in his case i just need to subscribe this channel (/chat) which reply me data , i m in mess here can you please help

Comment: Yes. After subscribing to that event you will receive data whenever the data is emmited from the server. Then you can update your varibles inside the subcribe method. That will result to update the view if you correctly bind the varibles in the html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173460/discussion-between-bhagvat-lande-and-anuradha-gunasekara).

Answer (score 1):

@Bhagvat Lande

I think you are looking for this :

https://angular.io/guide/observables

[getting live data from server continuosly and refelect changes in html in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47451177/getting-live-data-from-server-continuosly-and-refelect-changes-in-html-in-angula)

Comment: thanks . i need to get done this with help of SockJS and Stompjs , because my server is in Spring its recommended to use Sockjs and Stompjs